# "Unexpected character encountered" with Newtonsoft.Json reading GCP auth file

Tags: c#, json, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to get a local c# program that I have to connect to GCP (Bigquery).
I have gotten a credentials json file from GCP which looks something like:

```json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project-id-1",
  "private_key_id": "veryprivatekeything",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nmany_letters_and_symbols_here\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "bq-access-for-test@project-id-1.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "1234567891011",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/bq-access-for-test%40project-id-1.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

My code looks something like:

```cs
  string path2key = "C:/Users/me/Downloads/project-id-1-letters.json";

  byte[] jsonBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path2key);

// I also tried another encoding but same deal
// string jsonString = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(jsonBytes); 
  string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(path2key);
  Console.WriteLine(jsonString);

// This is where the error is
  string jsonStringDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(jsonString);
  Console.WriteLine(jsonStringDeserialized);

// I presume I'm passing json as a string???
  var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(jsonStringDeserialized);
  if (credential.IsCreateScopedRequired)
  {
     credential = credential.CreateScoped(new[]
     {
        BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery
     });
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Credentials Created");

  var client = BigQueryClient.Create("projectId", credential);
  Console.WriteLine("Client Created");
  var table = client.GetTable("bigquery-public-data", "samples", "shakespeare");
  var sql = 
      $"  SELECT corpus AS title" +
      $"      , COUNT(word) AS unique_words " +
      $"  FROM {table} " +
      $"  GROUP BY title " +
      $"  ORDER BY unique_words DESC " +
      $"  LIMIT 10"
   ;

  var results = client.ExecuteQuery(sql, parameters: null);

  foreach (var row in results)
  {
     Console.WriteLine($"{row["title"]}: {row["unique_words"]}");
  }
```

However when I get to the line that tries to deserialize the jsonString it complains that

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.'
```

I'm assuming the json isn't malformed as it was downloaded directly from GCP and I've checked with linters that it's valid.
What's the next thing I should be trying?

Comment: you are trying to desrialze into a string, thats means the json should just be a string, it is a complex object not a  string. YOu need to desrialize into a class object

Comment: @pm100 `GoogleCredential.FromJson()`  is expecting a string. If I just pass it the `string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(path2key);` then I get a different error about ` 'Error deserializing JSON credential data.'`

Comment: i was commenting on this line string `jsonStringDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(jsonString);` maybe you should just pass the json directly to that google call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don' t need this code, it doesn' t create anything , except the error

```
  string jsonStringDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(jsonString);
  Console.WriteLine(jsonStringDeserialized);
```

try just this

```
 string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(path2key);
  var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(jsonString);
 .... your code
```

Comment: That also didn't work. The error I get there is `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error deserializing JSON credential data.' FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.`
This error is why I (naively) added the deserialize.
The file is found, because I can print it out to check the path/file exists.

Comment: I'll open the above comment as a separate question. If it turns out that you are correct and I was wrong (highly likely) to try and deserialize, I'll come back and mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @infinityplusb - This answer is correct but you have another problem (missing package). See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71624767/8016720

Comment: Note that `GoogleCredential.FromFile` is a simpler way of achieving this.