# "Error Deserializing JSON Credential Data" gcp auth file c#

Tags: json, .net, google-cloud-platform

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71624221/unexpected-character-encountered-with-newtonsoft-json-reading-gcp-auth-file), I'd like to open a related one to verify an answer.
Originally my code looked like

```cs
  string path2key = "C:/Users/me/Downloads/project-id-1-letters.json";
  string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(path2key);
  Console.WriteLine(jsonString); // this works and prints correctly

// I presume I'm passing json as a string???
  var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(jsonString);
```

but I was getting the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error deserializing JSON credential data.' 
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm using netframework 4.5, meaning I'm somewhat limited in updating packages to the latest and greatest.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct. I was about to post the same answer but @serge beat me to it.

The class [GoogleCredentials](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential) has a member [FromJson](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential#Google_Apis_Auth_OAuth2_GoogleCredential_FromJson_System_String_). That member takes a **string** argument. In your code, you were trying to pass an object.

For the error in your comment to the answer:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions
```

That error can be corrected by using nuget package manager and adding **System.Security.Permissions** or via the CLI:

```
dotnet add package System.Security.Permissions
```

Comment: As mentioned, I'm using netframework4.5, so I can't add the `System.Security.Permissions` as the minimum framework for that package is `4.6.1`.

Comment: @infinityplusb - Then I am not aware of an easy solution for you. When you installed the package **Google.Apis** or **Google.Apis.OAuth2**, you should have noticed the warnings. Although Google.Apis supports .NET Framework 4.5 the dependencies do not. .NET Framework 4.5 was released 10 years ago. Suggestion, which I have not verified. Remove the Google and Newtonsoft packages. Then add Google.Apis.OAuth2. That should attempt a dependency install. If you get errors, then your only solutions are to not use the SDK or update the framework.

Comment: @infinityplusb As a test, set the credentials using **gcloud auth application-default login**. Then remove the code that uses a service account. The BigQuery Client will then use the CLI credentials. That can help you get started while a solution is found for the package problem. `var client = BigQueryClient.Create("projectId");`